# Как запустить .bat файл в бэкграунде?

Tags: cmd, bat

Имеется .bat файл, который при запуске начинает выполнять различные действия в command line. Есть ли возможность сделать так чтоб функционал .bat файла выполнялся, но при этом чтоб сам comand line был в бэкграунде ( вернее говоря чтоб пользователь не видел, разве что только в TaskManager ) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Средствами командного процессора этого сделать нельзя. Но можно, например, запустить процесс в скрытом окне, используя запускающий VSB-скрипт... хотя разумнее весь батч переписать на VBS или PS.

**UPD:**

По просьбе ТС подробнее.

Создай на диске C: каталог \Temp. 
Создай в нём 2 файла.

A.BAT

```
ping -n 1000 127.0.0.1 > c:\temp\ping.txt
```

B.VBS

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\Temp\a.bat",0
```

Открой Диспетчер задач, перейди на вкладку "Процессы".
Запусти файл b.vbs на исполнение (просто двойной клик по нему).
Убедись, что:

1. В процессах появятся, и через некоторое время исчезнут cmd.exe и ping.exe.
2. В каталоге появится файл ping.txt, и, пока не завершатся процессы по п. 1, файл будет заблокирован.
3. В файле сохранён протокол работы утилиты ping.
4. Ни окно CMD, ни окно PING на панели задач не появляется.

И можно не спешить скакать по окнам, пинг будет работать минут 10-15...

Comment: Прошу прощения, просто я только навичок, но может у Вас будет под рукой какая нибудь статья или любой другой материал с инструкциями ?

Comment: WScript.Run "filename.bat",0

Comment: Не очень понял, можно мне новичку объяснить поподробнее

Comment: Для продвинутых - можно было обойтись одной строкой **WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "c:\Temp\a.bat",0**

Comment: Спасибо огромное, завтра попробую !!!

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь дополнительной программой **cmdow**
https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/

```
cmdow /run /hid myprog.bat
```